# Converting AAC stream to DASH MP4 with high fragment length precision

Tags: ffmpeg, aac, mpeg-dash, media-source

For my HTML5 project I need to create a fragmented MP4 file with a single audio stream (no video), each fragment of which has a duration of exactly 0.1 second.

Accordingly to ffmpeg docs, you can accomplish that by passing a value in microseconds with '-frag_duration' - which I found to be working and playable with HTML5 MediaSource API:

```
$ ffmpeg -y -i input.aac -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 64k -level:v 13 -r 25 -strict experimental -movflags empty_moov+default_base_moof -frag_duration 100000 output.mp4
```

As we have a 210 second audio split up by 0.1s fragments, I expect that in output.mp4 we'd have 2100 fragments, hence 2100 moof atoms. But, upon inspecting it I've figured out that we only have 1811 moof atoms - which means that some (or maybe even all) fragments are bigger than expected:

```
$ python ~/git/mp4viewer/src/showboxes.py output.mp4 |grep moof|wc -l
1811
```

Could anybody tell me what's wrong, and how could I accomplish what I want?

Right now my assumption is that during an encoding I have AAC frame length which is not a multiple of 0.1s, hence ffmpeg has no chance to produce the fragments that are strictly equal to 0.1s but I'm not sure. If somebody can confirm that - and let me know a way to explicitly set AAC frame_size in FFMPEG (I couldn't find anything like that in the docs), or completely disprove this - it would be also highly appreciated.

Comment: AAC is fixed 1024 samples per frame and your audio appears to be 44100 Hz, so each frame is 0.0232 ms. So the best effort to 10 ms is 5 frames. Which predicts 1808 segments for a source exactly 210 s long. AFAIK, there's no way to set frame size.

Comment: What you could try if the duration is that important is to encode the full AAC to PCM, then segment using the segment muxer to 0.1s segments. Then encode each WAV to AAC in MP4 with a `-t 0.1` argument and also the movflags you're using.

Comment: Thanks for your info, now I tried with frag_duration=116000 and found it working as expected (1811 * 0.1160s = 210s). I will just use this value instead of 0.1s, that's no problem for my application.